# modify url address in python

Tags: python, url

I'm trying to add strings into a URL address in order to get data from a server. 
the string depends on a user input. the user input i saved under a variable called id.

```
id = str(raw_input("Enter a valid ID: "))
```

my url address looks like this:

```
url = "http://www.test.com/?%s&%s" % (id, api_key)
```

when i'm printing the URL just to check I've got everything in order i get this result:

```
http://www.test.com/?<built-in function id>&ef50250
```

I followed some other questions and some other tutorials but none seem to clearly it for my.
It is my first project so excuse if i ask any obvious questions.

Comment: `id()` is name of built-in function. Try to give the `id` variable different name.

Comment: Can you double check whether you actually run `id = str(raw_input("Enter a valid ID: "))` before `url = "http://www.test.com/?%s&%s" % (id, api_key)`. Is it in the same scope (same function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` is a built-in function. Give a different name to your variable. By the way, `raw_input` returns `str`. So you can get rid of `str(raw_input(...))`

```
>>> my_id = raw_input("Enter a valid ID: ")
Enter a valid ID: 12
>>> api_key='abc'
>>> url = "http://www.test.com/?%s&%s" % (my_id, api_key)
>>> print url
http://www.test.com/?12&abc
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful! The 'my_id' variable is found inside a function I defined. When I try to call it in the URL it say that 'my_id' is not defined. What should I do to make the value of 'my_id' the same from inside and outside the function?

Comment: You have to make that function return my_id and use that while building url